# How can I get the tick values of a '.nice()'ed scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a chart in D3 which contains grid lines. I'm placing my gridlines at every tick on my axis using the axis' scale:

```
y0Scale.ticks()
```

The problem I'm having is that the value of `.ticks()` doesn't seem to take into account the face that the scale has had `.nice()` called. The result of this is that sometimes my chart is missing gridlines at the extents of the axes.

I know I could combine `y0Scale.domain[0]` and `y0Scale.domain[1]` with the tick marks I know about, but doesn't always work, as in some cases the `.nice()` algorithm does more than just adding a tick value on the min and the max of the scale.

Comment: It is my understanding that this should work -- are you getting the ticks *after* calling `.nice()`?

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I had a base chart that was delegating out the range setting. Reviewing the ordering of my delegation was the solution. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.ticks()` *after* having called `.nice()` on the scale.